# ACCESSING BLOCKCHAIN ON "ESP8266" USING THE "NODEMCU BOARD"

Tags: go-ethereum, parity, light-clients, iot

I have read this example where it tries to interact with the Ethereum blockchain via a **micro-controller** (`ESP8266` and `NODEMCU` board). However, I do not understand if an Ethereum client (`Geth` or `Parity`) has been installed on this device? **If yes**, exactly on `ESP8266`  or `NODEMCU`? And **if no**, **how** this device can **interact directly** with the blockchain **without** installing an Ethereum node client?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot run geth or parity on an ESP8266, it is simply too underpowered.

Your best bet would be to expose the RPC on an actual node, and invoke the calls over http from the ESP.

Comment: Thank you.  Do you mean using an existing node such as "infura"? And also what do you mean by "ESP"? Thanks.

Comment: Infura may work, as long as you limit yourself to non-tracing, and non-log calls. ESP is ESP8266

Comment: Thank you. And is there any other (or better) options than `infura`? There are also 2 other examples ([HERE Elkrem](https://devpost.com/software/elkrem-development-board-for-iot-ethereum) and also [HERE](https://hackaday.com/2017/11/09/iot-with-the-ethereum-blockchain/) in which ESP8266 connects to a Wi-Fi router running an instance of a Go Ethereum node). Which one do you think has better structure? And btw, in case of using `Raspberry Pi` do we have the same situation? Thank you

Comment: No, raspi is much more powerful so that would work. The bigger brother of the esp8266, the esp32 might work too. Another, though of course questionable solution would be to access an api by a third party. And just for clarification, ESP8266 is the general chip. Nodemcu is an implementation of a dev board, that has power regulation, usb and debug access and connection to more pins.